# Failed to convert object of type <class 'zip'> to Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am implementing K-nearest algorithm in Tensorflow from the book "Getting started in Tensorflow" , But I am getting the error when I am setting the zipped variable as tensorflow constant . Here is my code:

```
x_values = []
y_values = []
vector_values = []

for i in range(num_vectors):
    if np.random.random() > 0.5:
         x_values.append(np.random.normal(0.4,0.7))
         y_values.append(np.random.normal(0.2,0.9))
    else:
         x_values.append(np.random.normal(0.1,0.3))
         y_values.append(np.random.normal(0.15,0.6))

vector_values = zip(x_values,y_values)

vectors = tf.constant(vector_values)
```

The idle is showing the error :

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  <'class 'zip'> to Tensor. Contents: <'zip object at 0x000001AE523EFE08>. Consider casting elements to a supported type

Comment: ... have you considered casting the `zip` object to a supported type?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the OP probably doesn't know how to

Comment: @SurajKothari right, well then the OP should *elaborate* on exactly what they don't understand. StackOverflow isn't a debugging service. It is a question-and-answer site, and questions need to show a little bit of effort besides "I'm getting and error" or "this didn't work".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True. He needs to show us what he is expecting as his output.

Comment: In Py3 `zip` returns a `zip` object, not a list.  To create an array or `tf` object that expects an array or list, you have to 'flesh it out' , `list(zip(....))`.

Comment: @hpaulj I got corrected my self by adding list before zip function like list(zip(x,y)) , Thanks

Comment: @hpaulj I got corrected my self by adding list before zip function like list(zip(x,y)) , Thanks

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj